# Obtain clear fringes from interferometer

Tags: optics, laser, fourier-transform, interference, interferometry

I have just begun setting up an interferometer to take some measurements. I am trying to reproduce one paper I found in literature for 3 DoF homodyne interferometry. The detector is merly a CMOS sensor. Here is a picture of the paper I am trying to reproduce: from the spatial interference pattern, these guys managed to extract information about relative tilts and displacements between the mirrors applying FFT algorithms to each pixel line.
[image]

Applying FFT to their picture, I got something similar like that (for only one [pixel line), and it seems to agree fairly well apart from the scale.
However, when I try to do the same to a fringe pattern I got from my setup I obtain this:
[image]

[image]

The intensity is not sinusoidal adn there are plateaus where the maximum intensity is detected: is there a way to get more spacing, or smoother fringes?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in part due to the small dynamic range, the ratio between the maximum and minimum measurable light intensities, of your detector.
This is a problem often encountered whenever one tries to "photograph" fringe patterns and you can usually tell if an image is real or simulated by looking to see if there are overexposed fringes or not.

Reducing the intensity of the fringes which are being analysed by your detector sufficiently should enable you to analyse the "expected" fringe intensity pattern.

Comment: Thanks! 
The dynamic range of the sensor is up to 69 dB and the minimum exposure time is 0.040 ms. If I understood right, to visualise fringes properly I should either decrease the exposure time (it was already set to the minimum) or increase the dynamic range? This would mean change the detector!
Could a higher frame rate help in that sense?

Comment: Could you use a neutral filter to reduce the intensity?

Comment: You are probably right. As I am pretty new to optics, I cannot even imagine the existance of some components, or how to concisely describe any issue!
I have now a couple of questions:

- can a 0.8 mW laser damage the CMOS sensor? Apparently I already have some dark spots...;
- is there a way to understand which neutral density filter I should need for my application?

Comment: Like Farcher said, just decrease the power hitting your detector if all the electronics are already set to their minimum sensitivity. Farcher should have mentioned that you are saturating your detector (going above its maximum capability), hence you do not obtain information. If I dump 12.367 L of water to you and you only have a 5L bucket, all you can measure is 5L and how much I exactly gave you is lost. So, decrease the signal going into your detector until you see a smooth image and not an overblown/saturated one.

Comment: I would not think that a 0.8mW beam could damage a CMOS detector (unless if it is ultrashort or very very tightly focused). Are you sure that the dark spots are not just small dust particles on the sensor/optics?

Comment: I would think the same from what I have been reading in literature! When it comes to actually build the setup, a lot of factors become evident (so beautiful!). 
Another question: as the interference pattern is visible only if the beams are superimposed, would it be useful to expand the beam from the laser source, before it passes through the beamsplitter? Would the interference always be detected in this way?

Comment: if you expand the beam you will naturally have less power on the detector. Now, if expanding the beam before your beamsplitter is fine or not depends on: 

1-whether you are already at the maximum of the clear aperture of the beamsplitter or if you still have space to expand it; 2-Your experiment is not sensitive to that kind of manipulation. Assess what you want/are measuring and decide.

Comment: I'm usong this self-contained laser from Thorlabs: https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=HNLS008L#ad-image-0 and a 1" cube beamsplitter, I guess I could expand the beam quite a lot! I obtained the image of the fringes expanding the interfering beams with a plano concave lens between the beamsplitter and the detector, I guess that the intensity can be reduced also in this way? (clearly not enough) Which would be the main drawbacks of expanding the beam just after its source?

Comment: @Gianluca Drawbacks to beam expansion: (a) cost of more components, (b) space used by those components, (c) added alignment sensitivity (and by extension, sensitivity to lab environmental fluctuations), (d) possible degradation of beam collimation if misaligned. On the other hand, if your beam isn’t well collimated to begin with, you could use a telescope to improve it! Overall, expanding the beam is relatively easy and inexpensive. I recommend it if it makes sense for you!

Comment: There are beam expanders that seem to cost quite a lot, but I guess that a combination of plano-concave and plano-convex lenses would work the same, right? The main problem is the budget unfortunately, and I can try if things work up to a certain limit. In this paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6501/ab7f79/meta) I think they expand the beam (using a quite expensive triplet), making the setup more similar to a Twyman-Green interferometer rather than a Michelson. Is there any cheaper alternative?